# TemplateSyntaxError in Django View

Tags: python, django

I use polls app on my project.
URLs on Polls App

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

In the detail template file, I create a form and when I click the submit button I want to go to the vote page.
so I make the form element like this

```
<form action="{% url polls:vote question.id %}" method="post">
    {$ csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" >{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

But when I build the project, I can see the Error during template rendering error in this form.
The error is:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ':vote' from 'polls:vote'
```

Please help me to check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change here

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for more info